# How to take data from a dynamic loading website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to extract data from a news paper website but problem is , its automatic reload in some fix time duration then how can i get data from that site and use it in my own website as a information. Data can be in image or text, anyone can tell me the process to take out data from any website.

Thanks

Comment: You can use RSS feeds for getting content from other websites, if that website having RSS feed option

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look up if the newspaper have a public api or RSS feed as mentioned.
If not thiss wil not be able to use professional.
Ofc you may strip down the html by tags, id-s or classes where you can kindof make it into a json. This might lead to leagal problems, not recommended.